# How do I give __init__ the arguments it wants?

Tags: python-2.7, arguments

I am trying to draw a sine wave as a beginner python project. So far everything was going as smoothly as possible for me, but when I started working on drawing lines between points, I started to get the Error mentioned below, which hasnt happened before. As I am fairly new to programming in general, I don't understand a) what `__init__()` is and does and b) what it means by "arguments" and where I am giving it too many/of the wrong kind (also I dont really know what a class is so try to keep your answer simple)

As stated before, the program used to work fine under python 2.7 on windows 10 64bit until I added the

```
l = Line(prex, prey, x, truey)
l.draw(win)
```

bit.
I have tried putting everything in a seperate class as I have seen it work in a similar example, this has however only led to more problems and confusion and since it didnt sem to help I have abandoned this approach.
I have tried googling and looking on the internet but I havent found anything that has satisfied me.

```py
from math import sin
from graphics import *

def main():
    global x      #sets up variables and defines start values
    global y
    global truey #used for drawing points
    global prex #used for drawing lines between points
    global prey #used for drawing lines between points
    truey = 1
    x = 1
    y = 1
    prex = 0
    prey = 0

    win = GraphWin("Sin wave", 1000, 500) #creates the window
    for i in range(1, 1000): #repeats the "logic"
        x = x + 2.3 #goes along the x-axis to repeat calculations
        y = sin(x) #calculates y-value which will be used later
        truey = (y * 100) + 100 #calculates actual y value used to draw 
        c = Circle(Point(x, truey),2) #draws a point  to represent wave
        l = Line(prex, prey, x, truey) #connects points with lines, WIP
        l.draw(win) #draws the line, WIP
        c.setFill("black") #fills "points"
        c.draw(win) #draws circles
        print truey 
    win.getMouse() #keeps window open
    win.close() #keeps window open 

main()
```

And the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lion/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/Sin wave.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Lion/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/Sin wave.py", line 23, in main
    l = Line(prex, prey, x, truey)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (5 given)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `__init__` is a function that is automatically called when creating a new object in Python and its job is to initialize the new object. I don't know what `Line` is but apparently you are giving it 2 too many arguments. Arguments are what yo "feed" to the function call inside the parenthesis `(...)`

Comment: After looking [here](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/graphics.html), `Line` takes 2 points. So you need to change to something similar to what you did with `Circle`. Like: `l = Line(Point(prex, prey), Point(x, truey))`. By the way the reason it tells you it takes 3 arguments but now I am telling you to give it 2 is because there is a default argument, `self` which is always there. But as you said you don't know classes, let's leave it with that. You'll learn it pretty soon

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now that you point it out, its obvious why it didn't work, so thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. Why don't you have a quick look in that link I put. It is some kind of a  tutorial to work with `graphics`. Sounds like it might help you